# Osciloscope output timing header meaning and interpretation

Tags: oscilloscope, sampling

I have obtained a set of readings from a set of oscilloscope data, RTA 4004 from R&S. the readings headings kind of puzzle me. It has an index.csv and multiple readouts.csv. The index.csv looks something like this

[image: Index.csv picture]

And the C1_0.csv looks like this

[image: C1_0.csv]

The rest of the csv (C1_1, C1_2,....C1_n) looks similar. From what I observed, the sampling seems to be done at 0.4ns. The total length of one record (C1_x) is around 1.224 us.

My task is to form a continous signal waveform from this capture. Hence my question is more focused on the index.csv

1. Is the meaning of thousandths in ms really meant 0.8596383072 ms (for C1_1)
2. Is the Time field to be combined with thousandths in msec to give an actual real recording time eg 16:07:02.0008506383072 (for C1_1.csv)
3. Does this time refer to the start of recording or end?
4. If 2 and 3 is correct, this will mean that the signal overlap one another (ie part of C1_1 overlaps with C1_2? and in certain part of signal there is no signal at all (consider inbetween zone at C1_4 and C1_3)
5. Is the time the output time(write on disk time or the actual acquisition time)? at loss at which direction should my sequence start from?

THanks for your help

Comment: Speak to the manufacturer of the scope.

Comment: @Andy aka. Thanks for the recommendation